# How to make new list from existing two list in python?

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
first_list = ['head1', 'head2', 'head3', 'head4']

second_list = [['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'], ['val1a', 'val2a', 'val3a', 'val4a'],...]
```

`second_list` is a query result.

I want a new `new_list` looks like below:

```
[['head1': 'val1', 'head2': 'val2', 'head3': 'val3', 'head4': 'val4'], ['head1': 'val1a', 'head2': 'val2a', 'head3': 'val3a', 'head4': 'val4a'],..]
```

How can I achieve the above result?

Comment: The desired output is not valid ( `'head1':'val1'` specifically). Do you mean a list dictionaries instead of list of lists?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your real question? Also this is not a valid Python structure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> first_list = ['head1','head2', 'head3', 'head4']
>>> second_list = [['val1','val2','val3','val4'],['val1a','val2a','val3a','val4a']]
>>> [dict(zip(first_list, val)) for val in second_list]
[{'head1': 'val1', 'head2': 'val2', 'head3': 'val3', 'head4': 'val4'}, {'head1': 'val1a', 'head2': 'val2a', 'head3': 'val3a', 'head4': 'val4a'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
first_list = ['head1','head2', 'head3', 'head4']
second_list = [['val1','val2','val3','val4'],['val1a','val2a','val3a','val4a']]
res = []
for ind, lst in enumerate(second_list):
    li = {first_list[ind]: lst[ind] for ind, _ in enumerate(lst)}
    res.append(li)
print(res)
```

Comment: The first `enumerate` is not necessary (the `ind` is never used) and the second one can be replaced with `zip`

Comment: This is also working. Thank you very much for the response.